# Sorting tlpdb.tlu output

Tags: texlive, luatex, lua

I get an output from tlpdb.tlu, which is unsorted. When I now use `table.sort` the output as a pdf is still unsorted.

```
tlpdb = read_tlpdb( kpse.var_value("SELFAUTOPARENT") )
table.sort(tlpdb)
```

Do I need a compare function for this?

Comment: This question belongs on stackoverflow.com, it's a question about the Lua language.

Comment: The code snippet is part of a tex document!

Comment: That's a bit like asking about `ls` in the following example: `\write18{ls}\bye`. As far as I understand that question, it is about sorting a Lua table. Which is a Lua question to me. If you disagree, you should expand your example a bit more. Where is `read_tlpdb` defined? It is **not** from LuaTeX. Please write more to get better help.

Comment: I presume the snippet is from question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38131, I updated my answer there to show how to get a sorted list of table keys.